# why my second tabsetpanel is not showing the output?

Tags: r, shiny

I created a getfile() function to get the file. In the case of first tabsetpanel it's showing the output while in case of second one it's not showing anything even though the codes are similar.

```
 library(shiny)
    ui <- fluidPage(
      headerPanel("Customer Segmantation"
                  ),
     mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
                   tabPanel("Data View", tableOutput("AD")),
                   tabPanel("Exploratory Data Analysis"),tableOutput("ED")
                    ),width = 8
          )
     )
    getfile = function()
    {
      return(read.csv("Mall_Customers.csv"))
    }
    server <- function(input, output) {
      output$AD<-renderTable({
        file1 = getfile()
        print(head(file1))
     })
      
     output$ED<-renderTable({
          data = getfile()
          print(head(data))
        
    })
     }
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: a good tip is to use the ctrl p keys inside Rstudio, so you can see where each parenthesis closes

Comment: Here is what you need: `tabPanel("Exploratory Data Analysis", tableOutput("ED"))` ... this is due to incorrect parentheses...

Comment: @Ben Thanks, now it's working fine.

Comment: Never saw Ben's comment when I posted my answer.  That is weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change `tabPanel("Exploratory Data Analysis"),tableOutput("ED")`

to `tabPanel("Exploratory Data Analysis",tableOutput("ED")`

You have an extra `)` after `"Exploratory Data Analysis"`.  That meant you never stated to display `ED` to the second `tabPanel` as you closed the parenthesis too early.